# Tengo un problema con Fullcalendar y el INNER JOIN framework Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, join, fullcalendar

Ya actualice mi publicación, ya me reconoce el id del proyecto y me hace el JOIN bien, en un alert se puede ver el resultado de la consulta, ya me pinta el calendario pero como si estuviera vacío. Las fases no las coloca.

Lo que pretendo es unir fases de proyectos, estas fases son de acuerdo a tiempo y de acuerdo a usuarios. En la consulta JOIN entran las siguientes tablas

> -> Proyectos
>
> -> Fases
>
> -> fases_proyecto
>
> -> Usuarios
>
> -> usuarios_proyectos

El resultado que espero son las fechas y el nombre de las fases que contenga el Proyecto 1, por ejemplo, pero obviamente lo tengo que verificar con la sesión del usuario logeado.

Tengo mi vista

```
    <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css" rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href='<?php echo base_url();?>assets/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
    <script src='<?php echo base_url();?>assets/fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
    <script src='<?php echo base_url();?>assets/fullcalendar/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='<?php echo base_url();?>assets/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
    <script src='<?php echo base_url();?>assets/fullcalendar/locale-all.js'></script>
    <input type="hidden"  value="<?php echo $idProyecto ?>" name="idProyecto" id="idProyecto">
    <script type="text/javascript">  var idProyecto = $("#idProyecto").val(); </script>
    <script>
     
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $.post('<?php echo base_url('index.php');?>/calendario/getFasesR/'+idProyecto,//-->NO MOVER
          function(data){
            alert(data);
            console.log(data);
            
          $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
          locale: 'es',
          header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
          },
          defaultDate: new Date(),
          navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
          editable: true,
          eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
          events: data
          
        });

      });


        
        
      });

    </script>
    <style>

    
      #calendar {
        max-width: 800px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }

    </style>


    </head>
  <body> 
  
  <div id="calendar">
    
  </div>
<br>

  <!-- jQuery library 
  <script src="<?php// echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>  -->
 <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed 
  <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script> -->  
  
 
<!--EliminaUsuario
  <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/userElimina.js"></script>-->
  <!-- Custom js 
  <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/custom.js"></script> -->
  
</body>
</html>
```

Mi Controlador

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Calendario extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();  
       
        $this->load->model('Fase_model');
    }
    function index(){
        
    }
    
    public function getFasesR($id){
        
        $fases = $this->Fase_model->getFasesByAs($id, $this->session->userdata('idusuarios'));
        //$fases = $this->Fase_model->getFasesR();
        echo json_encode($fases);
    }

}
?>
```

Y este mi función en modelo

```
 function getFasesByAs($idproyecto, $idusuarios){
        $this->db->select('f.idfases id, f.nombreFase title, f.fechaInicioFase start, f.fechaFinFase end');
        $this->db->from('fases_proyecto fp');
        $this->db->join('proyecto p', 'fp.proyecto_idproyecto = p.idproyecto');
        $this->db->join('fases f', 'fp.fases_idfases = f.idfases');
        $this->db->join('proyecto_usuarios pu', 'pu.proyecto_idproyecto = p.idproyecto');
        $this->db->join('usuarios u', 'pu.usuarios_idusuarios = u.idusuarios');
        $this->db->where('fp.proyecto_idproyecto',$idproyecto);
        $this->db->where('pu.usuarios_idusuarios',$idusuarios);
        return $this->db->get()->result();
}
```

Después del console.log(data)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63134/discussion-on-question-by-yadira-franco-tengo-un-problema-con-fullcalendar-y-el).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si deseas al cargar la pagina

```js
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
     var id = $('#idproyecto').val(); 
     $('#calendario').fullCalendar({ 
       header: { 
       left: 'title', 
       center: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month', 
       right: 'prev,next today' 
    }, 
    editable: false, 
    firstDay: 1, 
    selectable: true, 
    defaultView: 'month', 
    events: 
    { 
      url: '<?= base_url() ?>calendario/getFasesR/'+id, 
      textColor: 'black', 
      editable: true 
    }, 
   }); 
}); 
</script>
```

esa es la manera correcta de hacerlo
no es necesario hacer un post antes
ya que en evets mediante la url le indicamos de donde va saquar el json que debe mostrar el calendario
en tu caso la ruta de tu controlador
al cual le paso el id proyecto
que obtengo mediante var id = $('#idproyecto').val();